# How to get character position in a text file encode in UTF-8 in C?

Tags: c, file, text, utf-8, file-io

The C Standard specifies that `ftell()` returns the position of a character from the beginning of the file when it's opened in binary mode.

> ... obtains the current value of the file position indicator for the stream
> pointed to by stream. For a binary stream, the value is the number of characters from
> the beginning of the file. For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified
> information, usable by the fseek function for returning the file position indicator for the
> stream to its position at the time of the ftell call; the difference between two such
> return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written
> or read.

If the text file has a wide character, like `ñ`, then the position of any char after `ñ` would be greater than the corresponding column in the text file. Just to be specific, what I mean for position here is that the corresponding column if one read the text file as a linear sequence of symbols.

For example, the string `" ñ ñññ a ñ a"` has 12 char, but printing `ftell()` inside this loop:

```c
void printPosition(FILE *file){
    
    int c;
    long i;
    while((c=fgetc(file)) != EOF){
        i = ftell(file);
        printf("%c %i\n", c, i);
    }
}
```

gives the output:

```
  1
├ 2
▒ 3
  4
├ 5
▒ 6
├ 7
▒ 8
├ 9
▒ 10
  11
a 12
  13
├ 14
▒ 15
  16
a 17
```

I tried opening in text/binary read mode and got the same result for both.

Comment: UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding. One "character" could use one to four bytes. The C functions `fgetc` and `ftell` are *not* UTF-8 aware. And `ftell` could give wrong results depending on the system (e.g. text-mode files on Windows, where newlines are two bytes).

Comment: And when you mention "wide characters", do you mean `wchar_t` characters? Which could be many different encoding and sizes. On Windows perhaps they are UTF-16 encoded, which is *also* a variable-length encoding, and 16 bits. On many Linux systems `wchar_t` is four bytes, with no specified encoding.

Comment: If you want the position of the encoding of a Unicode Code Point, you will need to calculate/remember it. Files handles have no concept of Unicode Code Points.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, They mean Unicode Code Points, or maybe simply characters that may take up more than one byte. The file is encoded using UTF-8, so it obviously doesn't contain `wchar_t` objects.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I mean in the general sense, more than 1 byte size character

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There is a library for multi-byte char in C?

Comment: [This UTF-8 C library](https://juliastrings.github.io/utf8proc/) looks kindof wow.   I think you'll need it for even the most basic kind of character-in-array-search-to- determine-file-offset method mentioned earlier.

Comment: Tip: Don't call `ftell` after reading each character (byte). Just add one to a counter!

Comment: What are you asking here? Are you trying to calculate how many Unicode *code points* precede the given character in the file? Note that code points are not characters either; there are characters that are combined from multiple code points.

Comment: The `ftell` function is useless for character encoding details. It can record a location in a stream that you can accurately return to with `fseek`.   Also, regarding binary, on POSIX platforms, there is no difference between binary and text stdio streams: the ISO C `b` flag is accepted, but doesn't do anything.

Comment: @ikegami I was thinking of that, but I need a function who can skip a wide char of 2 bytes ore more and then add to a counter. Because when i want to find that specific character, I'd need that position. I don't now how fseek/fsetpos is implemented, but I think they are faster that reading all the file from 0 position to the position I want.

Comment: @Kaz -- I think OP wants to know file offset of each UTF-8 character beginning byte.  But yes, let's let Daniel speak.

Comment: @Kaz I want to know offset of each char, as greg says.

Comment: Re "*I need a function who can skip a wide char of 2 bytes ore more and then add to a counter*", Yes, that's what I said. You need to calculate it. /// Re "*I want to know offset of each char, as greg says.*", No, you want the position of the encoding of each Code Point.  You'll need to calculate it yourself (as I previously mentioned), and store it (since you want it later).

Comment: To get the length of a UTF-8 character/codepoint, see the `utf8len` function in my answer: [How to convert uppercase/lowercase turkish letters to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77512900/5382650)

Comment: Offset ... *in what units*? Clearly not bytes; you got that, but it somehow doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: @Kaz, Offsets of the encoding of each code point (or maybe extended grapheme clustes), in bytes. So if the file contains C3.89.72.69.63, they'd want offsets 0, 2, 3, 4

Answer (score 1):

IF your platform supports `UTF-8` compatible locale, you can use wide characters to read the file wide char by wide char.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
int main() {
    {
        char *r = setlocale(LC_ALL, "C.UTF-8");
        if (!r) {
            perror("Could not setlocale to UTF-8");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    // Create a temporary file with the requested content in your question.
    {
        const char str[] = " ñ ñññ a ñ a";
        FILE *f = fopen("/tmp/temp", "w");
        assert(f);
        int r = fwrite(str, 1, strlen(str), f);
        assert(r == strlen(str));
        r = fclose(f);
        assert(r == 0);
    }
    // Read the file using wide characters.
    {
        FILE *f = fopen("/tmp/temp", "r");
        assert(f);
        unsigned counter = 1;
        wint_t c;
        while ((c = fgetwc(f)) != WEOF) {
            printf("Character %lc at char position %u ftell=%ld\n", c, counter, (long)ftell(f));
            counter++;
        }
        int r = fclose(f);
        assert(r == 0);
    }
}
```

Executing the program gives the output on godbolt https://godbolt.org/z/cdbrGKPss :

```
Character   at char position 1 ftell=1
Character ñ at char position 2 ftell=3
Character   at char position 3 ftell=4
Character ñ at char position 4 ftell=6
Character ñ at char position 5 ftell=8
Character ñ at char position 6 ftell=10
Character   at char position 7 ftell=11
Character a at char position 8 ftell=12
Character   at char position 9 ftell=13
Character ñ at char position 10 ftell=15
Character   at char position 11 ftell=16
Character a at char position 12 ftell=17
```

> if one read the text file as a linear sequence of symbols.

I am not sure if "linear sequence of symbols" makes sense in unicode. The required reading on unicode is [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) . You might be interested in [libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/) and [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/) libraries for unicode handling in C.

Comment: IMO, `printf("Character %lc at position %u\n", c, counter);` would be more illuminating with `printf("Character %lc at position %u ftell:%ld\n", c, counter, ftell(f));`.